# apache - Changes to RewriteRule in .htaccess not taking effect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using WAMP and I want to remove `index.php` from my url and I used this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then I had to change two lines as I moved my files to sub-directory `OOP-Project` from:

```
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) OOP-Project/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ OOP-Project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

But, the changes are not taking effect although first time it worked! I tried adding syntax error and it showed the error. Surprisingly, when I moved my files to another folder say `OOP-Project-1`, it worked. I did a lot of research and found this [Changes to RewriteRule in .htaccess not taking effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970186/changes-to-rewriterule-in-htaccess-not-taking-effect) But it didn't address the problem correctly.

Hope someone helps!